# pop objects out of a stack

Tags: c++, loops, optimization, coding-style

Let's say I want to pop objects out of a stack and check their state, whether it's `FUP` (facing up) or not.

I want to keep doing this until I reach a point where the stack is empty OR an instance's state is not facing up; in this case I need to push this instance back and stop looping.

Here's one way of doing it:

```
bool isfup = true;

while(pop(stack, &ins) && isfup = ins->state == FUP)
{
    // continue removing elements from stack
}

if(isfup == false)
    push(stack, ins);
```

and here's how I do it:

```
while(pop(stack, &ins) && (ins->state == FUP || (push(stack, ins) && false)));
// while( A && ( B || ( C && false ) ) );
```

My question is, Should I stop writing code this kind of style and go for clarity? or should I keep it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put it in a function using the long and clear way, and then call the function in one quick line when you need it invoked. That is the one of the purposes of functions in procedural programming, after all! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Your metacode would crash if the stack was initially empty or became empty.
Also as a matter of style, inspect the top element and then either pop or continue

```
while(!stackEmpry(stack) && (top(stack)->state==FUP)) { pop(stack); }
```

Answer (score 1):

Any non-throwaway program will read by you or someone else many times more than write. This coding style takes longer to write, even longer to read, doesn't run any faster and error-prone. What are you trying to accomplish?

In the good old days when people print out code in paper you might have an excuse, but in this day and age and retina display is everywhere...